# Massive MySQL update best approach?

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

I need to update the stock levels in my MySQL database 3 times a day from a CSV file.

The CSV has over 27,000 products in there to be update and as you can imagine it takes a little while.

I currently have a php script that runs the following:

```
select * from products where product_code = "xxxxxxx";
if num_rows > 0
    if new_stock_level = 0
        UPDATE products SET `stock` = 0, `price` = 9.99 where product_code = "xxxxxxx";
    else
        UPDATE products SET `stock` = 50, `price` = 9.99, `stock_date` = now() where product_code = "xxxxxxx";
```

This is all well and good if you are updating < 50 items but not 27,000!

What would be the best way to do an update of this scale?

I have been doing some reasearch and from what i can see mysqli prepared statments seem to be where i should be heading.

After trying some of the bits mentioned below and what i have read online i have had the follwoing results with a batch of 250 updates.

Changing from InnoDB to MyISAM on average increased the number of ubdate per sec from 7 to 27 which is a massive increase to start with.

Prepareing the statment with case 9-10 sec

```
## Prepare the statment.
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE products SET stock = case ? when 0 then 0 else ? end, price = ?, stock_date = case ? when 0 then stock_date else now() end WHERE product_code = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('dddds', $stock, $stock, $price, $stock, $prod);
$stmt->execute();
```

Non Prepared statment 9-10 sec

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET stock = case " . $stock . " when 0 then 0 else " . $stock . " end, price = " . $price . ", stock_date = case " . $stock . " when 0 then stock_date else now() end WHERE product_code = \"" . $prod . "\";\n";
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

grouping statments in 50's and excuting with multi_query 9-10 sec

```
$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

Non prepared with 2 seperate querys depending if im updating the stock date or not. 8-9 Sec

```
if($stock > 0)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE products SET stock = " . $stock . ", price = " . $price . ", stock_date = now() WHERE product_code = \"" . $prod . "\";\n";
}
else
{   
    $sql = "UPDATE products SET stock = " . $stock . ", price = " . $price . " WHERE product_code = \"" . $prod . "\";\n";
}
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

prepared version of the same 8-9 sec

```
## Prepare statments
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE products SET stock = ?, price = ?, stock_date = now() WHERE product_code = ?;");
$stmt1->bind_param('dds',$stock, $price, $prod);
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE products SET stock = ?, price = ? WHERE product_code = ?;");
$stmt2->bind_param('dds', $stock, $price, $prod);

if($stock > 0)
{
    $stmt1->execute();
}
else
{   
    $stmt2->execute();
}
```

I aslo tried addeding an additional processor to the VPS and it made it about 4 querys a secound faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things about this ...

```
1. you can do this with one sql statement 
UPDATE products 
SET stock = case new_stock_level when 0 then 0 else new_stock_level end, 
    price = 9.99,
    stock_date = case new_stock_level when 0 then stock_date else now() end
WHERE product_code = "xxxxxxx";

2. you might want to try wrapping the statements inside of a transaction:
e.g.
START TRANSACTION
UPDATE products ...;
UPDATE products ...;
... ;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

These two things should speed it up.

Comment: also about your original post, if you're checking for the existence of a row, i would do a select * - that drags the entire row across the network (if your server is on a different machine). better off just selecting one field (select product_code ...)

Comment: in the above, i *meant* to say "i would NOT do a select *"

Answer (score 6):

You can use MySQL's [CSV storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/csv-storage-engine.html) to make a table that accesses your CSV file directly.  No need to import it.

Then you can use [multi-table UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) to join the CSV table directly to your `products` table using the `product_code` column.  Then you can update columns of `products` based on the columns read from the CSV table.

Comment: +1 for the CSV storage engine... but how would one go about wiring it up. Create table then swap out the underlying file?

Comment: Yes, that works.  Of course you need to put the CSV file in the right place under the data directory, and make sure it's read/write for the `mysql` user.

Comment: And would probably be a good idea to create some indexes because I imagine the performance is abysmal without them.

Comment: You can't create indexes on CSV tables, but yes it's important to have the right indexes on the products table.  E.g. I'd first try an index on (product_code, stock).

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a little bit out o fmy legue at the moment but i will look in to this for the future.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would upload the updates into a temporary table create a unique key on the product_code field then run an update like this...

```
UPDATE tmptable p, products pp 
SET pp.stock = p.stock,
    pp.price = p.price,
    pp.stock_date = if(p.stock == 0, now(), pp.stock_date)
WHERE pp.product_code = p.product_code
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know this is not directly an answer to your question, but I'd like to suggest a different approach.

Instead of trying to update the **entire** stock level, try updating only the things that have  changed since the last update? You could use some sort of change time to track it.
This would heavily depend on your environment, but potentially selecting current stocks and compering them against the csv file (or the other way around) could actually be faster that updating every single record. Of course, this could be a complete waste of time, but there is only one way to find out...